# Hibernate criteria DB2 composite keys in IN clause

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, db2

Hibernate criteria, using DB2 dialect, generates the following SQL with
composite keys in the `IN` clause, but DB2 answers that the query is incorrect:

```
select * from tableA where (x, y) IN ( ( 'x1', y1) )
```

but, DB2 throws this:

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "," was found following ", y) in (
('x1'". Expected tokens may include:  "+".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

Comment: How does the critera call looks like, may be the mistake is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax would be

select * from tableA where (x, y) IN (**VALUES** ( 'x1', y1) )

Note you specify the VALUES clause only once, so a multiple rows results could be obtained with

select * from tableA where (x, y) IN (**VALUES** ( 'x1', y1), ( 'x2', y2)  )

Don't know how to make Hibernate do it, however.